# change UI at runtime from view controller

Tags: ios

I have a view controller that loads a custom view(which in turn draws UI elements, then spawns a thread to do some things in the back ground.

If the "things that run in the background", encounter an error, my view controller catches it, and at this time I want to change UI elements, like bgcolor or add a new label.

But any changes I make are not showing up. This is what I'm trying:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onCompleteFail) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

- (void)onCompleteFail
{ 

  NSLog(@"Error: Device Init Failed");

  mLiveViewerView.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
  //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  UILabel *tmpLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 30)];
  tmpLabel.text = @"Failed to init";
  [self.view addSubview:tmpLabel];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make any UI-related calls on the main thread: UIKit is not thread-safe and you’ll see all kinds of weird behavior from acting as if it is. That could be as simple as switching something from

```
[self onCompleteFail];
```

to

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onCompleteFail) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

…or if `-onCompleteFail` has to be called on the background thread for other reasons, you can wrap your UI calls in a dispatch to the main queue, like this:

```
- (void)onCompleteFail
{ 
    NSLog(@"Error: Device Init Failed");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          mLiveViewerView.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
          //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
          UILabel *tmpLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 30)];
          tmpLabel.text = @"Failed to init";
          [self.view addSubview:tmpLabel];
    });
}
```

Comment: I already am performing this on the main thread. That is not the issue.

Comment: @Siavash: Maybe you need to call `setNeedsDisplay`.